# How do I formulate the .ajax POST to an Action Method in Controller and Return to another Action Method?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have been struggling with this approach for an entire day, I have my .ajax POST hitting the right action method, but my issue is after it performs the POST/Update to the database, I am trying to return using RedirectToAction("Add_Contract", "Contract", model) to display my "Add_Contract" view, my problem is that the "Add_Contract" view NEVER appears, the "Add_Dataset" reappears. I need to use the POST to update the dataset data to reload later, and display the View for "Add_Contract" so I can enter the contract information, then reload the "Add_Dataset" View with the updated Contract information.

I think my problem is in .ajax formulation:

Here is my Ajax (Called from Add_Dataset)

```
   $("#AddContract").click(function () {

        var contractAdd = "true";
        var datasetID = $("#dataset_Id").val();
        var datasetPK = $("#Dataset_PK").val();
        

        // Dataset Form Data
        var data = new FormData;
        
        data.append("datasetId", datasetID);
        data.append("Dataset_PK", datasetPK);
        data.append("add_Contract", contractAdd);

         

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: key + "/Datasset/Add_Dataset/",
            data: data;
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (ajaxRespond) {
                if (ajaxRespond.dbUpdateResult == "success") {
                    
                }
            }

        })
    })
```

Here is the Action Method:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add_Dataset(Dataset model)
        {
            BaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseServiceUrl"];
          


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
  
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Create a Dataset Record 
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //HTTP POST
                var postTask = client.PutAsJsonAsync<Dataset>("api/datasets/" + model.Dataset_ID, model);
                postTask.Wait();

                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    if (!model.add_Contract)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Add_Dataset");
                    } else
                    {
                        **return RedirectToAction("Add_Contract", "Contract", model);**
                    }
                }
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Add_Dataset");

        }
```

Add_Contract

```
 // Add a Contract
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Add_Contract(Dataset model)
        {
             var returned = new Contract();
             return View(returned);
}
```

Comment: Redirecting in response to an AJAX request makes no sense. The whole point of using AJAX (as opposed to a standard postback) is to allow the browser to _stay on the same page afterwards_. Therefore, the AJAX client ignores the redirect headers issued by your server when you call RedirectToAction. If you need/want to do a redirect after sending your  data, then just post a form and don't bother with AJAX.

Comment: I thought so, I am afraid I am not an expert at jquery. I think I know what to do. Thanks

Comment: It's nothing to do with jQuery, it's about how Ajax and http work. But essentially if you want the redirect to work, get rid of Ajax and just use a normal form.

Comment: Thanks again, I am just going to perform a submit from that link

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is almost working perfectly. Thanks a bunch